# blue smudges displayed on iPhone MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, mkmapview

Occasionally, blue smudges are displayed in my MKMapView.
Seems to be related to me manually re-sizing and moving around the map.
Iphone6+ and iPhone7+
Xcode 8

[image]

CODE THAT DRAWS THE BLUE ROUTES.....................

ADD THE ROUTE OVERLAY:

```
            // Draw route line (Add data for map route from prev location to latest, if prev):
                CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateArray[2];
                coordinateArray[0] = GPS_location_file[ previous_record ];      // prev GPS
                coordinateArray[1] = GPS_location_file[ new_record_index ];         // this latest GPS

                //  Sets MKPolyline routeLine to these 2 latest route points:
                view_controller.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinateArray count:2];

                //[view_controller.mapView.visibleMapRect:[view_controller.routeLine boundingMapRect]]; //If you want the route to be visible

                // Adds new overlay with latest two route lines to map:
                [view_controller.mapView addOverlay: view_controller.routeLine];
```

RESPOND TO DELEGATE REQUEST TO DISPLAY ROUTE ON MKMAPVIEW:

- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView         rendererForOverlay:(id)overlay 
  {
  printf("\n%s: ", **FUNCTION** );
  //if(overlay == self.routeLine)
  //{
  //  printf("\n  self.routeLine");
  //  if(nil == self.routeLineView)
  //  {
  //      printf("\n  nil == self.routeLineView");

  ```
      MKPolylineRenderer *renderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
      renderer.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
      renderer.lineWidth = 4.0;            
      return renderer;
  ```

  //  }
  //  return self.routeLineView;
  //}
  //return nil;
  }

Comment: given that your path is drawn in blue, I suspect it has to do with that.  Can you show the code you use to draw the path on the map?

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I'm with the exactly same problem